# best practices for using Categorical Variables in H2O?

Tags: machine-learning, h2o, feature-selection, categorical-data

I'm trying to use H2O's Random Forest for a multinominal classification into 71 classes with 38,000 training set examples.  I have one features that is a string that in many cases are predictive, so I want to use it as a categorical feature.

The hitch is that even after canonicalizing the strings (uppercase, stripping out numbers, punctuation, etc.), I still have 7,000 different strings (some due to spelling or OCR errors, etc.)  I have code to remove strings that are relatively rare, but I'm not sure what a reasonable cut off value is.  (I can't seem to find any help in the documentation.)

I'm also not sure what to due with nbin_cats hyperparameter.  Should I make it equal to the number of different categorical variables I have?  [added: default for nbin_cats is 1024 and I'm well below that at around 300 different categorical values, so I guess I don't have to do anything with this parameter]

I'm also thinking perhaps if a categorical value is associated with too many different categories that I'm trying to predict, maybe I should drop it as well.

I'm also guessing I need to increase the tree depth to handle this better.

Also, is there a special value to indicate "don't know" for the strings that I am filtering out?  (I'm mapping it to a unique string but I'm wondering if there is a better value that indicates to H2O that the categorical value is unknown.)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

High cardinality categorical predictors can sometimes hurt model performance, and specifically in the case of tree-based models, the tree ensemble (GBM or Random Forest) ends up memorizing the training data.  The model has a poor time generalizing on validation data.

A good indication of whether this is happening is if your string/categorical column has very high variable importance.  This means that the trees are continuing to split on this column to memorize the training data.  Another indication is if you see much smaller error on your training data than on your validation data.  This means the trees are overfitting to the training data.

Some methods for handling high cardinality predictors are:

- removing the predictor from the model
- performing categorical encoding [[pdf]](https://kaggle2.blob.core.windows.net/forum-message-attachments/225952/7441/high%20cardinality%20categoricals.pdf)
- performing grid search on `nbins_cats` and `categorical_encoding`

There is a Python example in the [H2O tutorials GitHub repo](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials) that showcases the effects of removing the predictor from the model and performing grid search [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/best-practices/categorical-predictors/gbm_drf.ipynb).